# Way to prefix controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there any way to set custom folder controllers prefix like routes in laravel 5.6?

```
Route::get("/", "Foo/Controller@method");
Route::post("/", "Foo/Bar/Controller@method");
Route::get("/index", "Foo/Bar/Controller/Controller@method");
```

I want this

```
Route::get("/", "Foo::Controller@method");
Route::post("/", "Foo::Bar.Controller@method");
Route::get("/index", "Foo::Bar.Controller.Controller@method");
```

Comment: If my answer doesn't work for you, make your question more clear on why you would need this sort of prefix.

Comment: It's only for writing comfort, solution with group does not suit me

Comment: Why is it easier to write Foo:: over Foo\ ?  When you're referencing classes, Foo\ seems more natural to me.

Comment: Nothing, i like entry like Foo::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can group your routes and set a starting namespace for the entire group:

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Foo'
], function () {
    Route::get("/", "Controller@method");
    Route::post("/", "Bar\\Controller@method");
});
```